# Unable to consume RestFul web service using jersey client

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, resteasy

My service side code is implemented using Resteasy

```
@GET
@Path("/ad-details/{query}")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getAdDetails(@PathParam("query") String id)
{
    //Validator v =  ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(id);
    //String id1 = ;
    //System.out.println(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(id1)));
    String adDetailsResult = "";
     System.out.println("reached Service");
    AdServiceProvider ad = new AdServiceProviderImpl();
    AdDetails details = ad.getAdDetailsById(Long.parseLong(id.trim()));
    adDetailsResult = gson.toJson(details);
    //System.out.println(adDetailsResult);
    //adDetailsResult = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(adDetailsResult));
    System.out.println(adDetailsResult);
    return adDetailsResult;


}
```

and my client side code consuming this service is using jersey api 
and the code is as mentioned below.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("reached servlet");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String adId = request.getParameter("adId");
    System.out.println(adId);
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource wr = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/com.pandora.services/service");
    String adDetailsResult = wr.path("ad-details").path(adId).get(String.class);

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(adDetailsResult);
}'`
```

however when i make a call i am getting the following error

> WARN org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher Failed to parse request.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type '*; q=.2'
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:80)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:53)
>       at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:173)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.util.MediaTypeHelper.parseHeader(MediaTypeHelper.java:204)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletUtil.extractAccepts(ServletUtil.java:119)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletUtil.extractHttpHeaders(ServletUtil.java:82)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:186)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Expected separator '/' instead of ';'
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextSeparator(HttpHeaderReader.java:117)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:91)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:78)
>       ... 21 more
>   May 10, 2011 7:14:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletInputMessage.(HttpServletInputMessage.java:60)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.createHttpRequest(HttpServletDispatcher.java:71)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.createResteasyHttpRequest(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:197)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>       at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   May 10, 2011 7:14:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet AdDetailsServlet threw exception
>   com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: GET http://localhost:8080/com.pandora.services/service/ad-details/1 returned a response status of 500
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:565)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:182)
>       at com.pandora.client.servlets.AdDetailsServlet.doPost(AdDetailsServlet.java:48)
>       at com.pandora.client.servlets.AdDetailsServlet.doGet(AdDetailsServlet.java:34)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

where am i making the mistake ??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is this:

> `Error parsing media type '*; q=.2'`

Which makes me think I should be looking for problems with some sort of media-type-related header of the request from the client. Perhaps you should specify a MIME type for the response. It looks like you expect the service to return JSON, so how about [specifying the `Accept` header](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#accept%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType...%29) in the request?

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource wr =
    client.resource("http://localhost:8080/com.pandora.services/service");
String adDetailsResult = wr.path("ad-details").path(adId)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

Comment: HTTP headers of the request/response are useful than any stacktrace when using a restful web service. The response headers indicates accepted content types; and JSON is not, because it falls in the * (everyone else). Looking at the response header is enough to know how you can interact with this resource.